# What is stackoverflow.xluat.com, and is it a dodgy fake site?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

So I found this site http://stackoverflow.xluat.com/

Does it have anything to do with the StackExchange company? Or is it a phoney hoaxy type of thing. And if it is, how do they get away with using the same name?

Comment: [What is stackoverflow.xluat.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258885/what-is-stackoverflow-xluat-com)

Comment: Uhm that is kinda my question, @hvd

Comment: Heh, I gave you a link to a question titled "What is stackoverflow.xluat.com?", I'm not asking you that question, sorry for being unclear. :)

Comment: Haha my bad @hvd

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258885/what-is-stackoverflow-xluat-com

Comment: when I tried to open this site, my company show blocked page, so seems something not correct

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a site that is a copy of stackoverflow. I don't know exactly what it is, but it seems to be using to stackexchange api to get the questions. Pick a random question and remove the "xluat" part and you see the exact same question on stackoverflow(the real one). However, I still recommend caution there.

Very intresting fact:

[image]

Comment: Also, another note. The domain name is "xlaut.com". Its kinda like "gaming.stackexchange.com" where "stackexchange.com" is the domain name. Could be a wrapper for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also found [this](http://xluat.com.webstatsdomain.org/).